# Call Android activity from notification

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to call an activity class from the notification using the following code

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(con, 0, new Intent(con,
MyActivityClass.class), 0);
```

But when try use this `MyActivityClass.java` is not getting invoked.Pleae help.

Is there anything in addition that I need to do?

Any help is much appreciated.

Br,
Rony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(con, 0,new Intent(con,
MyActivityClass.class), android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(con,MyClass.class);
intent.putExtra("myMessage", myMessage);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(con, 0, intent , android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


I am trying to retrivr this value from MyClass.java as
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle !=null)
        {
            message = bundle.getString("myMessage");
           
        }

I am not getting any values